# AngularJS simple "Hello, world" not working

Tags: angularjs

Trying to follow a tutorial, I can't get the "Hello, world" example working. Instead it displays: "{{greeting.text}}, world". Using Chrome and AngularJS 1.3.1.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
            <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

**My folder structure**

```
root/
    angular.js
    app.js
    index.html
```

Thank you

Comment: if You're not using any http server and just open index.html from disk, Your browser will not allow to load scripts from disk. Is that Your case?

Comment: @Jarema it will allow you to load scripts, just not ajax. he isn't performing any ajax.

Comment: AngularJS by Brad Green and Shyam Seshadri (http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449344856_sampler.pdf).

Comment: But it works on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JvdXxhgQA0d3SryVnsPD?p=preview

Comment: @nikoloza seems to only work with the old version of angular you included, not the latest.

Comment: @KevinB it worked on the latest as well :)

Comment: @nikoloza what am i doing wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/UwuGwmOrJ2AdbscZbLwl?p=preview

Comment: You are right, on the latest version it failed. Is it a bug? checking changelog now...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I hope this helps.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appname">

  <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);
appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XmliRcmsZvuQimHoyjN5?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Mind explaining the "['$scope'" portion? Or pointing me to a good tutorial?

Comment: But why previous one does not work? Do they changed something?

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy Don't worry about it, I only just started learning AngularJS myself. I found the NG-Book really helpful but you can find most examples / tutorials on Plnkr / Codepen just as good. Regarding the $Scope here is a link telling you everything you need to know. 

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: that book is nice, but have lot of errors in code, unfortunately :(. I suggest taking https://www.codeschool.com/ course. Its free - sponsored by google. nice and elegant.

Comment: Might be worth checking out these video tutorials - http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-fundamentals

Answer (score 13):

Answering the question of what is wrong and if they changed something.

- AngularJs Version 1.2 or older: The controller could be a function not defined into a module. Like in the question.

Controller

```
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

- Angular Version 1.3 or newer: The controller must be defined into a module. Like in the answer.

Controller

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);
appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
        Enter text:
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="hellomodel" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1>
            {{hellomodel}}</h1>
        <script language="javascript">
            var myapp = angular.module("myApp", []);
            myapp.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.hellomodel = "Hello World!";
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/222/AngularJS-Hello-World.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is good but I thought I'd chip in with some resources I've found helpful if you're looking for a better understanding of how things work in Angular

- Egghead.io  - www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7
- Shaping up with Angular www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Both are completely free courses and because the egghead.io playlist is split into videos for separate concepts it's also really good reference material.

The [angular.js developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) is also really helpful!